# Get a "callback" for (loss of) connectivity change in a Service

Tags: android

Specifics: I have a service that runs the notification cast controls (CastCompanionLibrary). When I lose connection, the cast manager doesn't try to tear down the service quick enough. So if the user sleeps the device within a couple seconds of connectivity loss, the notification doesn't get taken down.

General Question:
How can I get a callback/alert of a connectivity change in a Service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can programmatically create a `BroadcastReceiver` in your `Service` that listens for the [ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#CONNECTIVITY_ACTION) action, calling [registerReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#registerReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver,%20android.content.IntentFilter)) when you want to start listening (say, in `onCreate()` or when you show the notification you eventually want to hide), then calling [unregisterReceiver()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#unregisterReceiver(android.content.BroadcastReceiver)) when you want to stop listening (such as in `onDestroy()` or when you remove the notification).

You can then retrieve the connectivity by using code such as

```
boolean isDisconnected = intent.getBooleanExtra(
            ConnectivityManager.EXTRA_NO_CONNECTIVITY, false);
```

in your `onReceive()` method.